# Variable changes its value mysteriously (to me at least)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Ok, I feel kind of awkward. I have this little assembler "program":

```
section .data
var dw 0x0

section .text
  global _start
  _start:
    nop
    cmp dword [var], 0x0
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Now, I initialize the variable "var" to 0x0. However, If I run this "program" through a debugger it says that the value of "[var]" at the line "cmp dword [var], 0x0" is actually 1835008. Now, why is that? I initialized it to 0 and I didn't do anything further to this variable, so it shouldn't change. Yet it has changed. Why? What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dw`, in NASM syntax, means "reserve word". A "word" in x86 architecture is 2 bytes, or 16 bits, mainly due to historical reasons. 32-bit data is referred to as "doublewords". In NASM syntax, `dd` can be used to "reserve doubleword".

After changing `var dw 0x0` to `var dd 0x0`, the program works as expected. The value 1835008 (0x001c0000) apparently includes some other data that just happened to be located after `var`'s starting address.

Comment: Oh my, I thought dword has been deduced from "dw" which stands for "define word" or at least that's how I memorize it and so I thought dword is an mnemonic for dw and thought dword stands for a word and not a doubleword.